# how to read encrypted app.config appSettings in win console application?

Tags: c#, encryption, app-config

EDIT: This question made no sense. I mixed .vshost.config with exe.config. What to do with this?

Program.cs main:

```
databaseName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseName"];
databaseUser = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseUser"];
databasePwd = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabasePassword"];
port = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"];
logDirectory = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogDirectory"];
strLogLevel = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogLevel"];

EncryptConfigSection("appSettings");
```

This is how I encrypt the file:

```
private static void EncryptConfigSection(string sectionKey)
{
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionKey);

        if (section != null)
        {
            if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                if (!section.ElementInformation.IsLocked)
                {
                    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
                    section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;

                    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The file gets duplicated and encrypted just like in the examples I found in web:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings configProtectionProvider="DataProtectionConfigurationProvider">
        <EncryptedData>
           <CipherData>
<CipherValue>AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAvsQ9Wtc58EC5EZCEq91EogQAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAClVHhpR5xAw4KFNyrANtavAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAABHkhg2ztiY3bdWhTG9iy6twAAAAF5mAHt7oDQWCgc1iLL2hYUJZgmquU8XsojjqXVQdV1CaW3XEBXBDhN30DEZizP3F5rGGMCjL9CVjHfsPAfvVYyRHCcup22BoByb5y/MDujaASpaWZYcdxSxLijT/Zq3zB8hiWyWPruY0G7emYEOq/xQAAADkgStCMABwo3oZx/VXHD41wrsjXg==</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

But next time I start it, I can't read it. All read values are null. I naturally removed the original, unencrypted file from the folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `KeyValueConfigurationCollection` for the `appSettings` key and the `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection` for the `connectionStrings` key.

This encrypts when not encrypted and decrypts and prints out values when encrypted:

```
private static void CryptConfig (string[] sectionKeys)
{
  Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

  foreach (string sectionKey in sectionKeys)
  { 
  ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionKey);

  if (section != null)
  {
    if (section.ElementInformation.IsLocked)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Section: {0} is locked", sectionKey);
    }
    else
    {
      if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
      {
        //%windir%\system32\Microsoft\Protect\S-1-5-18
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(DPCP);
        section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypting: {0} {1}", section.SectionInformation.Name, section.SectionInformation.SectionName);

      }
      else
      { // display values for current config application name value pairs
        foreach (KeyValueConfigurationElement x in config.AppSettings.Settings)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value:{1}", x.Key, x.Value);
        }
        foreach (ConnectionStringSettings x in config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Provider:{1} Cs:{2}", x.Name, x.ProviderName, x.ConnectionString);
        }
        //
        section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
        section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypting: {0} {1}", section.SectionInformation.Name, section.SectionInformation.SectionName);
      }
    }        
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Section: {0} is null", sectionKey);
  }
  }
  //
  config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
  Console.WriteLine("Saving file: {0}", config.FilePath);      
}
```

App.config used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration> 
<appSettings>
<add key="DatabaseName" value="databaseName"/>
<add key="DatabaseUser" value="databaseUser"/>
<add key="DatabasePassword" value="databasePwd"/>
<add key="Port" value="port"/>
<add key="LogDirectory" value="logDirectory"/>
<add key="LogLevel" value="strLogLevel"/>   
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SecurePassDataBase" connectionString="Data Source=D-xxxx;Initial Catalog=DEMO;User ID=sa;Password=******" />    
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: eventhough my question was about why i didn't succeed and the answer was cause I was debugging and mixed the files (it was working perfectly, see EDIT-part in the beginning), I chose to accept this, cause u're right about using separate connectionString. I'm gonna use only that for dbname, user and pwd and encrypt only that (port, loglevel and logdir are not encryupted).

Comment: what is 'DPCP' here ?

Comment: either `DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider` or `RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider`

Comment: @andrei.ciprian can you kindly check this question and give your opinion regarding that? Please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70692032/how-to-access-keys-inside-sections-in-app-config

Answer (score 2):

here is a very simple code you can use

[RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Made some small modifications...

```
    static public void ProtectSection()
    {

        // Get the current configuration file.
        System.Configuration.Configuration config =
                ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                ConfigurationUserLevel.None);


        // Get the section.
        ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("appSettings");


        // Protect (encrypt)the section.
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");

        // Save the encrypted section.
        section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;

        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);

        // Display decrypted configuration  
        // section. Note, the system 
        // uses the Rsa provider to decrypt 
        // the section transparently. 
        string sectionXml = section.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();

        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted section:");
        Console.WriteLine(sectionXml);

    }
```

Comment: This one encrypted the file and displayed the decrypted value also. Perfecto!

Comment: It worked yesterday and did not work today on exactly same project. The errors are : 
1. ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to encrypt the section 'appSettings' using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'.
2. CryptographicException: Object already exists

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this & you'll get what you want :

```
        Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).ToString()).FilePath.ToString());

        string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).ToString()).FilePath.ToString());
        foreach (string s in readText)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```

Comment: This one displayed encrypted file as it is but not the decrypted values.