# How to save login credentials(username, password) in C# desktop application?

Tags: c#, json, database, authentication

I'm trying to figure out what is the best solution for saving login credentials. Should I save it to a file (like json) or in a database, and how to protect those information, because I'm designing a desktop C# app which will be stored in public directory which be accessible to several users.

Comment: There is no way to store and use credentials in an app and at the same time hide them from the user. Interesting read: Peter's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367241/how-to-store-ftp-credentials-securely-in-c-sharp-application)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Does every user log on to windows with a different account? Then I would try to make it single sign on. You could also store stuff in the profile, which should be locked away from other users.

Comment: It should be an application for a company. They have a directory where the app should be stored, and that directory is public, so everyone in the company have access to it.